# Call Objective-C native method from binding in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When you want to bind an Objective C method in Xamarin, you use the ExportAttribute to override it.

But how can you call the native code behind the now overriden method?

Example overriding UIButton's LayoutSublayersOfLayer native method:

```
[Export("layoutSublayersOfLayer:")]
public void LayoutSublayersOfLayer(CALayer layer)
{
    // base.LayoutSublayersOfLayer() <-- Any way to do this for bindings?
}
```

Without calling the native base of this method UIButton won't layout it's title nor it's image and internal stuff.

Any help is really appreciated as there is no documentation on the whole internet.

Answer (score 0):

You want to `override LayoutSublayersOfLayer` in your custom `UIButton` class and call the base method:

```
public class CustomButton : UIButton
{
    public CustomButton() { }

    public CustomButton(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

    public CustomButton(NSObjectFlag t) : base(t) { }

    public override void LayoutSublayersOfLayer(CoreAnimation.CALayer layer)
    {
        base.LayoutSublayersOfLayer(layer);
    }
}
```

In the `UIView` Class:

```
[Export ("layoutSublayersOfLayer:"), CompilerGenerated]
public virtual void LayoutSublayersOfLayer (CALayer layer)
{
    UIApplication.EnsureUIThread ();
    if (layer == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("layer");
    }
    if (base.IsDirectBinding) {
        Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (base.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("layoutSublayersOfLayer:"), layer.Handle);
    }
    else {
        Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr (base.SuperHandle, Selector.GetHandle ("layoutSublayersOfLayer:"), layer.Handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't directly override it as it's not defined in UIButton class nor any backing classes.

Comment: @Tylerian ? Yes, the backing method is defined in `UIView` :  `UIButton` -> `UIControl` -> `UIView`

Comment: Notice that the method is **LayoutSublayersOfLayer** and not **LayoutSubviews** therefore is not implemented in UIView class

Comment: @Tylerian I'm not sure where you are looking, but I added the **LayoutSublayersOfLayer**  backing method from `UIView` to my answer,,,

Comment: Are you working with MonoMac instead of Xamarin.iOS by any chance?

Comment: @Tylerian  No, `Xamarin.iOS`

Comment: Where are you looking for those methods? Are you using MonoTouch instead of Unified API? I can't even find the method on UIView Xamarin's documentation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122230/discussion-between-tylerian-and-sushihangover).

Comment: Tried chat, no reply... Unified API, straight from the `Assembly Browser` View (just hitting show dependency on the UIButton class , what version of Xamarin.iOS are you using?

Comment: I'm on chat now. Xamarin Version: 6.0.2 Build 73 and Xamarin.iOS
Version: 9.8.2.22

Comment: I'm on `9.10` for production and `9.99 (iOS 10 preview`) for working on upgrades towards the Apple iOS 10 release date. Assume that is the problem, if you are stuck on that version, you can just use the `Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr` & `Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr` to send the selectors manually from your subclass.